# How to hide the icons and only show the back button in the toolbar using navigation component?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, uinavigationcontroller

I have a single activity app with multiple fragments and by using the navigation components I can navigate between them. On my Activity, I have a toolbar with a menu and nav controller. The toolbar icons are shown in every fragment in my app and in one of the fragments, I want to show only the back button without the rest of the icons. How do I possibly do that?.

Thanks in advance..

You can use java or kotlin I understand them both

**My Main Activity**

```
 private lateinit var navController : NavController

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainerView) as NavHostFragment
     navController = navHostFragment.navController
    val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_nav)
    bottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController(navController)


    val my_toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.myToolBar)
    setSupportActionBar(my_toolbar)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
}
 override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu2, menu)
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
}
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId){
        R.id.filter_list -> Toast.makeText(this, "Filter Was Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        R.id.female_filtering -> Toast.makeText(this, "Female Filter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        R.id.male_filtering -> Toast.makeText(this, "male Filter", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    val navController = findNavController(R.id.fragmentContainerView)
    return item.onNavDestinationSelected(navController) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

**my menu**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<item
    android:id="@+id/favouriteFragment"
    android:title="المفضلة"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite"
    android:menuCategory="secondary"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/contactUsFragment"
    android:title="للتواصل"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_contact"
    android:menuCategory="secondary"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/filter_list"
    android:title="فلترة"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_filter"
    android:menuCategory="container"
    app:showAsAction="always">

    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/female_filtering"
            android:title="وظائف نسائية"
            app:showAsAction="never"/>
        <item android:id="@+id/male_filtering"
            android:title="وظائف للرجال"
            app:showAsAction="never"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

-- I don't have any code on my fragments regarding the toolbar

My main fragment

[image]

I only want to show the back button in this fragment

[image]

Comment: My guess is that you would need to not use `setSupportActionBar()` so you can use things like `addMenuProvider()` and [`invalidateMenu()` with your `Toolbar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/appcompat/widget/Toolbar#invalidatemenu).

Comment: As per the documentation, if you want a different actionbar/toolbar per destination then you need to define a separate toolbar/actionbar within the destination layout. please refer to this documentation. "https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui"

Answer (score 0):

please refer  https://stackoverflow.com/a/70527808/15529296 this link. It might be helpful.

Comment: Your link is not working

Comment: @Abood: i edited the link plz check again.